# Ubuntu 18.04 is hanging while starting

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lts

I had recently dual booted my PC, It was working fine but from couple days when I am trying to open it, it’s hanging and not starting. I tried restarting the PC but this hasn't worked, I am not sure what’s happening?

Please suggest to me what I should do.

A photo of the problem is here:

[image: Screenshot of boot messages]

Answer (score 0):

The screen with the text can appear sometimes. it necessarily doesn't mean that your pc is hanging. If it is slowing down, then it is most likely a hardware problem. Your PC does look a bit old. Many factors are at play here, for example, the RAM, processor, etc. Sometimes overheating can cause this as well.try maintaining the PCs insides. Cleaning it up, replacing the fans, etc. Although I would not recommend doing this if you haven't done it before. It would be best to get it checked by a local repair shop. Old PCs tend to be a bit unreliable.

Comment: hmm I think you right i should goto the repair shop, and yeah it's actually quite old 10yr. Thanks for help.